# pandas groupby tuple of different length - ValueError: Values not found in passed level: MultiIndex

Tags: pandas, group-by, multi-index

Edit: example DataFrame for the original error-message found and posted.

(As I just recognized, the Error does only appear, if the tuple has a certain length. The example is now adapted.)

Original text:

I need to group by tuple of different length.

For the grouping I'm applying a summary_function.

```
import pandas as pd

def summary_function(df):
    value_mean = df['value'].mean()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value_mean':[value_mean]
                        })
    return df1

tuple_list = [(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),(2,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), \
          (1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), \
          (2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)]

value = [1,2,3,4]
letter = list('abab')

df = pd.DataFrame({'letter':letter, 'tuple':tuple_list, 'value':value})
df

>    letter     tuple                                           value
>0  a       (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)             1
>1  b       (2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)             2
>2  a       (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)             3
>3  b       (2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ...   4
```

If I'm using a direct mean() function, the result is how expected:

```
df.groupby(['letter','tuple']).mean()

>                                                       value
>letter     tuple   
>a       (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)        2
>b       (2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)        2
>        (2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ...)   4
```

But if I apply the function. (which I need to use since I have dozens of summaries) The tupel is empty while using the simple

```
df.groupby(['letter','tuple']).apply(lambda x:summary_function(x))
```

I get a ValueError:

```
>ValueError: Values not found in passed level: MultiIndex([(2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)],
       )
```

It would be awesome to get some ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Change this `return df1` to `return value_mean` this should do the job.

Comment: Don't return a dataframe in `apply`, returns a single scalar only.

Comment: @Quang Hoang
The real function is not returning a dataframe with only one cell but with 2 dozen columns. Therefore it's not an option just to return a scalar.
Sure I could return 2 dozen parameters (scalars, arrays, lists). But I don't think that these things would be pasted nicely together through the groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, do not return the dataframe, return the series.

When you return the series, Pandas will align the series horizontally. For example:

```
def summary_function(df):
    return df['value'].agg(['min','mean','max'])

df.groupby(['letter','tuple']).apply(summary_function)
```

Output:

```
value                                                      min  mean  max
letter tuple                                                             
a      (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)             1.0   2.0  3.0
b      (2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)             2.0   2.0  2.0
       (2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1...  4.0   4.0  4.0
```

Comment: The solution was even more simple. I just replaced the pd.DataFrame with pd.Series.
And your answer inspired me to this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. One of my groupby columns (I have 2) contains tuples (either with 1 or 2 elements) and I return series in my "apply" function, but still get a "ValueError: Values not found in passed level: MultiIndex".   - any ideas?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The even shorter solution was just to replace "pd.DataFrame" with "pd.Series".

```
def summary_function(df):
    value_mean = df['value'].mean()
    df1 = pd.Series({'value_mean':[value_mean]
                    })
```

(Inspired by the answer of Quang Hoang)